How to fix seams in cubemap faces to equirectangular?
I am trying to convert 6 cubemap faces to equirectangular.
I created the skybox.blend by the following steps:

Create a box mesh
Assign 6 materials on it
Assign face texture on material
Create a camera on the box center
Change the Panorama Type to Equirectangular
Do rendering.

Here is the rendering result:

There are lots of seams on the edge of the face.
How can I fix the seams ?

Please don't use external sites for files which may not be available in future and require unzipping! You can share the Blend file directly here via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Your textures are too small and the filtering in the Image Texture node makes the colors of the top (white ceiling) bleed in the bottom when the tiling is set to Repeat.

The best you can do is setting the filtering to Closest (no filtering so visible pixels) or, if you want to keep the filtering, set the tiling to Extend to minimize the bleeding.

It works as expect ! Thank you for your help !
